# how to compare two objects using viewstate

Tags: asp.net

how to compare two objects using viewstate.
what is the meaning of below line.

```
if (!((byte[])ViewState["ROW"]).SequenceEqual(obj.RowID))
{
    return null
}
```

can anyone please help on this

Comment: do you want to know the meaning or are you facing any issue with the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **ViewState["ROW"]** : This part will retrieve data from the `ViewState` stored with key `ROW`
2. **(byte[])ViewState["ROW"]** : This part will `cast` your data stored in ViewState **to byte array**
3. **SequenceEqual** : is extension method from `System.Linq`, which checks whether two sequences are same or not
4. **((byte[])ViewState["ROW"]).SequenceEqual(obj.RowID)** : Compares sequence of  `ViewState["Row"]` and `obj.RowID`
5. **if (!((byte[])ViewState["ROW"]).SequenceEqual(obj.RowID))** : This will return `null` if sequences of `ViewState["Row"]` and `obj.RowID` are not same.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the meaning of below line.

Basically, [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a LINQ `Enumerable` extension function which desinged to determine if a source sequence (e.g. `byte[]`) is equals to another sequence.

Assuming you are comparing **two** byte arrays (sequenses) in your provided code, if they both equals in their *sequence of elements*, you will get `true`, otherwise, `false` would be the result.

For example, the following sequences are equals and the `SequenceEqual` will return `true`:

```
byte[] chars1 = {56,32,12,32,65, 87};
byte[] chars2 = {56,32,12,32,65, 87};

bool res = chars1.SequenceEqual(chars2); // Will return true
```